# Is it possible to see diagnostics/debug info when Windows attempts to Repair Wireless Connection?

Tags: windows-xp, router, wireless-networking

"Windows could not finish repairing the problem because the following action cannot be completed: Renewing your IP address"

I'm able to connect to a wireless network from a laptop machine just fine and the same is true for the iPhone but I can no longer connect using the desktop machine. Is it possible to trace communication between machine and wireless router?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the event logs to check if those give detailed information,
or you could try to do the failed action yourself, just start a 'command prompt' as an administrator and execute `ipconfig /renew`.